# UIImagePickerController using popover works well in iPad iOS 7 device but crash in iPad iOS 6 in LandScapeMode.

Tags: ipad, ios6, uiimagepickercontroller

UIImagePickercontroller works in landscape mode in ios7 for iPad but Problem in iOS 6 for iPad its crashing.
Please note that i am using UIPopOverController to display uiimagepickercontroller as suggested.

iam getting crash report below one.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'
```

Comment: Have you implemented `shouldAutorotate` method??